# Xen time drift in DomU's

Tags: time, xen

My Xen domu's keep drifting their times.  My dom0 is using kernel 3.2.0 for AMD 64.  DomU's are using 2.6.26.  How do you keep the time from drifting?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Domu's are getting drifted w.r.t your Dom0 time. In that case , you can do one of the following:-

1. Configure ntp (Network time protocol) on your Domu. It is a fairly simple process. You can make changes in your /etc/ntp.conf file (assuming it is a linux domu) to include Dom0 as a ntp server and then start ntp daemon ("service ntpd start"). This way domu can sync their time with Dom0.
2. Configure Dom0 and all Domu's so that they sync their time with an external server. Make changes in ntp configuration file of all and then restart ntp on all of them. This way all of them will be in sync with some external source and hence time drift should not happen.
3. For an immediate time sync , you can use "ntpdate" command on Domu.

Comment: Dom0 is actually very steady and never drifts very much at all.  It has ntp configured as do all of my DomUs.  I do use ntpdate to get an immediate sync.  I have to do it weekly otherwise DomUs get way off.